# Отсоединенный режим Ado.net

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

Пытаюсь реализовать отсоединенный режим работы с БД. Делаю это таким способом:

```
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=true;Initial Catalog=Sales;server=(local)");
            SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from albums", connection);
            SqlCommandBuilder build1 = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter1);
            DataTable alb = dataset.Tables.Add("albums");
            alb.Columns.Add("id", typeof(Int32));
            alb.Columns.Add("name", typeof(String));
            alb.Constraints.Add("PK_Customers", alb.Columns["id"], true);
            alb.Columns["id"].AllowDBNull = false;
            alb.Columns["name"].AllowDBNull = false;
            adapter1.Fill(dataset, "albums");
```

Но в данном случае нужно создать DataTable, заполнить всю информацию о полях, ключах и т.д., и аж потом можно получить все данные из базы, да и еще так нужно делать для каждой таблицы. Есть ли какой-то подход, чтобы не заполняя эту информацию можно было получить всю базу со всеми таблицами?

Comment: Вы хотите загрузить сразу всю таблицу в память?

Comment: @pavel, Именно так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общий принцип работы выглядит так, Вам необходимо:

1) Создать `SqlDataAdapter`.

`SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Users", connectionString);`

2) Создать объект класса `DataSet`.

`DataSet myDataset = new DataSet("MyDatabase");`

3) Заполнить объект класса `DataSet`

`sda.Fill(myDataset, "usersTable");`

Аналогичным способом Вы можете заполнить `DataSet` из других таблиц БД.

---

1) Настройка PrimaryKey

```
myDataset.Tables["usersTable"].PrimaryKey = 
         new DataColumn[] { myDataset.Tables["usersTable"].Columns["ID"] };
```

2) Задаем уникальность для PrimaryKey

```
myDataset.Tables["usersTable"].Columns["ID"].Unique = true;
```

3) Создание отношений между таблицами

```
DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("UserOrder",  
            myDataset.Tables["usersTable"].Columns["ID"], 
            myDataset.Tables["orderTable"].Columns["DebitorID"]);

myDataset.Relations.Add(dr);
```

---

Обновление данных в источнике

`sda.Update(myDataset.Tables["usersTable"]);`

Имейте ввиду, что для того что бы работало обновление, у вас у адаптера должна быть настроена команда `sda.UpdateCommand`

```
SqlCommand update = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Users SET Name = @Name" + 
"WHERE ID = @ID", connection);

update.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 15);
update.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 0);

sda.UpdateCommand = update;
```

Comment: а если в таблице которую я заполняю, есть внешние ключи на другие таблицы??

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: А после того как я поработал с этим кэшем, как изменения залить в базу?

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Comment: а в этом способе не нужно наспраивать autoincrement для `ID`? И как настроить команду `sda.UpdateCommand`?

Comment: Обновил ответ...

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, использовать типированый датасет. Вы здесь создаёте нетипированный и наполняете его таблицами/колонками в коде. Типированый датасет просто рисуете в редакторе.

Во-вторых, можно сделать SQL-запрос в котором выполняются сразу несколько запросов, например,
`SELECT * FROM Customers; SELECT * FROM Orders`

В коде который вызывает запрос -- делаем `while (reader.Read())` для выборки первой таблицы, затем `reader.NextResult();`, затем снова цикл `while (reader.Read())` для получения второй таблицы итд.